# What did i do wrong with this derivation?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, power-series, generating-functions

$$
\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\cos(x)} &= \frac{1}{1-(\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} - \cdots)}
\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} - \cdots)^n
\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-\cos(x))^n
\end{align}

This part i am okay with, but now i will attempt to find a power series of $\tan(x)$ in terms of $\cos(x)$ with the following reasoning:

I realised that by differentiating The secant function i would get $\sec(x) \tan(x)$ and by differentiating the series would also yield a $\sin(x)$, therefore i would end up with $\sec^2(x)$ (which is the derivative of $\tan(x)$) therefore by integration i would find myself a power series for $\tan(x)$ in terms of $\cos(x)$ I will do as i explained below:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}[\sec(x)] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}(1-\cos(x))^n
$$

$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)} = \sin(x) \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) (1-\cos(x))^n
$$

$$
\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) (1-\cos(x))^n
$$

Now to redefine $(1-\cos(x))^n$ by using the following identity:

$$
(1+x)^{\alpha} = \sum_{k=0}^\alpha {\alpha \choose k} x^k
$$

Therefore:

$$
(1-\cos(x))^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(-\cos(x))^k
$$

Now this is where i run into some doubt:

$$
\sec^2(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(-\cos(x))^k
$$
Since the following is true for ordinary power series:
$$
fg \longleftrightarrow \left\{\sum_k a_k b_{n-k} \right\}
$$

Therefore by setting $a_k = \frac{(-\cos(x))^k}{k!}$ and $b_{n-k} = \frac{1}{(n-k)!}$

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(-\cos(x))^k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)! e^{1-\cos(x)}
$$

This is clearly wrong obviously as the series does not converge... What was my error?

Comment: You're making things more complicated than they need to be at the beginning.  You can write $\displaystyle\frac 1 c = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-c)^n$ for $0<c<2$ and so that certainly applies to $c=\cos x$ whenever $\cos x>0$.  That does not in any way depend on the power-series expansion of $\cos x$, so bringing that in distracts from what's happening in that part of what you're doing. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: What does $ fg \longleftrightarrow \left\{\sum_k a_k b_{n-k} \right\} $ mean?  Also, what is your goal here?  To find a power series for $\tan(x)$, or to find a series for $\tan(x)$ in terms of $\cos(x)$?

Comment: I would assume it means that if $f = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $g=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ then $fg = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k} \right)$.  If I'm not mistaken, this is true if both series converge and one of them converges absolutely. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It means that:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n a_n
$$

$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n b_n
$$

$$
f(x) g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}
$$

My goal is to find a series for $\tan(x)$ in terms of $\cos(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(-\cos(x))^k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)! e^{1-\cos(x)}
$

The problem is that,
in your series,
only one of the terms
has the $x^n$.

Here is a more detailed examination
of what happens:

Let
$u = \cos(x)
$.
We have

$\frac1{u}
=\frac1{1-(1-u)}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-u)^n
$.

Differentiating term-by-term,
and then using the binomial theorem,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{-1}{u^2}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n)(1-u)^{n-1}\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(1-u)^{n}\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^ku^k
\text{  ( you need }u^n \text{ as well as } u^k)\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} (n+1)(\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!})(-1)^ku^k
\text{ (here is the problem)}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^ku^k}{k!}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)!}{(n-k)!}\text{ (the inner sum diverges violently)}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^ku^k}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+k+1)!}{n!}\\
\end{align}
$$

You can only do the
series multiplication
if the same variable
occurs in both series.

Comment: So either way the series diverges?

Comment: Yep. Yep.  Yep. Yep.